# Como fechar o uib-popover ao clicar fora?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Eu estou tentando utilizar o `uibPopover` do Angular UI Bootstrap para exibir um campo `input`.

O problema que estou tendo é que, ao clicar fora do popover, ele não está fechando.

Eu já procurei algumas respostas no `SOEN` que diz que eu tenho que definir o atributo `popover-trigger`como `outsideClick` ou `focus`. Tentei das duas formas, porém ainda não obtive o resultado esperado.

O código do botão que ativa o popover está assim:

```
<button  
    uib-popover-template="'popover-itens-protocolo.html'" 
    popover-placement="top-right" 
    popover-title="Nova Coluna" 
    popover-trigger="focus"
    type="button" 
    class="btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-plus-square"></i>
</button>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="popover-itens-protocolo.html">
    <form>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" ng-model="novaColuna" class="form-control" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button ng-disabled="!novaColuna" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="adicionarNovaColuna(novaColuna)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</script>
```

Qual é a solução para esse problema?

**Atualização**: Todos os exemplos que testei com `clickOutside` funcionaram perfeitamente, porém o meu não funciona. Não sei se o fato de o template está sendo carregado externamente possa influenciar no fato, mas é assim que estou fazendo.

Answer (score 1):

Fuçando o Github para lá e para cá, acabei descobrindo que é um problema de atualização.

Foi relatado em uma dos [Issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6228), que isso tinha sido removido a partir da versão 1.3.3.

Porém, ao ler outro Issue, foi informado que nas versões mais recentes do Angular UI Bootstrap, ao invés de usar `popover-trigger="outsideClick"` deve se usar `popover-trigger="'outsideClick'"`.

O Issue que eu li isso é [esse](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/6212)